# Parsing through many big files in folder using terminal command and outputting terminal output to text file (C/C++)

Tags: c++, text, terminal

I'd like to read in the output from a specified terminal command and store it in a text file. The terminal command includes a path to a file in which I'd like to loop through each file in a folder, and storing its output to terminal into a text file. I want to keep all the output in one text file in order.

For example,

I want to use a command in the terminal:

"Translate /data/xyzdata/raw/ne/VData*****.gz"

where Translate is a user built command which takes the .gz file and outputs it as ASCII on the terminal display. ***** represents the changing part of the file name each time as it parses through the contents of the folder.

Note that these files are enormous. This is data from particle physics detector.

Eventually, I'd like to parse through .../raw/**/... as well, going through a few other folders.

I'd like to take the text file and essentially read in the lines and sum the columns to produce histograms of hit rates per detector section.

A typical file looks like this:

00000000 00000010 00010001 11001100

where each digit is a section of the detector and a 1 represents a "hit".

Any ideas? I'm certainly open to trying something new.